# HorizontalSplitPanel - Adjust the splitter position based on component width

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, splitpanel

Is there a way to add more than 2 components in HorizontalSplit panel without nesting it?

Splitter position should be based on the space allocated for the component. There is nesting of horizontal split panel but the splitter position is not set based on the component visible space

Comment: It's probably a good idea to tag this question with the specific version you're using.

Comment: Seems no direct way to implement this solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a separate resizable split area for each of those components, then no, you cannot do that with just one split panel and nesting is indeed the solution. If you are fine with just one split, then you can add a layout instead of a component and just keep inserting more components to the layout.

You can use `splitPanel.setSplitPosition` for adjusting the split position. If your desired split position isn't static and your contents don't have fixed sizes, you could possibly use a tool like [SizeReporter add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/sizereporter) for querying the content sizes. Note that this will undeniably cause some flickering, because you need to add the component to the layout before you can measure its size.

Comment: But with adding the component in a layout can we adjust the width in the screen? I think split panel gives that option.

Comment: Do you mean the split position within the split panel, or the width of the entire split panel?

Comment: split position in a split panel . Dragging the spliiter from side to side

Comment: So if you have two items you want the split to be 50-50, and if you have three items you want the split to be 33-66 in the outer split panel and 50-50 in the inner split panel?

Comment: if we need split like 20-30-20-10-20 for 5 components, it should be adjusted in such a way the splitter positions is displayed irespective of main split panel or nested panel.

Comment: Edited my answer with some further suggestions for setting the split position.

Answer (score 1):

A horizontal splitpanel allows one component on the left and one on the right side.
Nothing more
What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Dynamically add components from the list of components. Currently we are using nesting of the horizontal panel when component numbers exceed 2. The goal is to set split position  after adding the components. Each component is given a fixed space in the horitzontal split panel. Splitter should be adjust according to the space alloted for that component.

Answer (score 0):

If you add two layouts to HorizontalSplit there is nothing stopping you in adding more than one component to those layouts. You can also add new SplitLayouts to existing splitlayouts if you want that.

Comment: Yes. But each component should display in specific width inside the split panel. If we adjust the width of the component, only component width is getting adjusted and not the splitter position. Acheiving it with nested split panel is not help much

Comment: @SujathaKannan You should edit your question to include that requirement.